# unidentified char preventing me from parsing coordinates into an int

Tags: c#

Ok I'll try and explain the problem although it's going to be a bit hard.

I'm trying to parse some information from a certain page containing coordinates.
and the copy paste give you something like this:

> Distance  Position
>   5.8     ‎‭(‭‭77‬‬|‭-‭2‬‬)‬‎
>   6.3     ‎‭(‭‭76‬‬|‭-‭1‬‬)‬‎
>   7.8     ‎‭(‭‭76‬‬|‭‭6‬‬)‬‎
>   9.2     ‎‭(‭‭91‬‬|‭‭3‬‬)‬‎
>   9.5     ‎‭(‭‭79‬‬|‭‭10‬‬)‬‎
>   12.2    ‎‭(‭‭80‬‬|‭‭13‬‬)‬‎
>   15  ‎‭(‭‭82‬‬|‭-‭14‬‬)‬‎
>   15  ‎‭(‭‭81‬‬|‭‭16‬‬)‬‎

now the problem that I have is that between the "(" and the number there is an unidentified char, if you press on the right arrow key it won't move but if you press few times then it will move.

I haven't encounter this thing anywhere, and the website is in php if that helps.
also if that helps when I copy paste the information in here the char disappear and I can move freely through the text.

Please help me with this problem since it's causing my software to malfunction since I'm trying to parse the coordinates into an int and because of that char it won't let me, it'll give me a format exception.

Comment: You're using C# *and* PHP?

Comment: I'm using C#, getting the data from a php website.

Comment: OK, removing PHP tag because it has nothing to do with the question. The source of the data is irrelevant.

Comment: @SagiRokach in that case the PHP bit is irrelevant. Don't worry about the implementation of the API you call, only the contract it defines.

Comment: "the copy paste gives you something like this" is meaningless, because it's the actual data being copied and pasted that is the issue. Save what you copied/pasted into a file, and then look at that file in a hex viewer to see what it actually contains so that you can identify that "unidentified char".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While viewing in UTF-8, I see nothing, while changing the encoding to ANSI, I am left with:

```
5.8 â€Žâ€­(â€­â€­77â€¬â€¬|â€­-â€­2â€¬â€¬)â€¬â€Ž
6.3 â€Žâ€­(â€­â€­76â€¬â€¬|â€­-â€­1â€¬â€¬)â€¬â€Ž
7.8 â€Žâ€­(â€­â€­76â€¬â€¬|â€­â€­6â€¬â€¬)â€¬â€Ž
9.2 â€Žâ€­(â€­â€­91â€¬â€¬|â€­â€­3â€¬â€¬)â€¬â€Ž
9.5 â€Žâ€­(â€­â€­79â€¬â€¬|â€­â€­10â€¬â€¬)â€¬â€Ž
12.2 â€Žâ€­(â€­â€­80â€¬â€¬|â€­â€­13â€¬â€¬)â€¬â€Ž
15 â€Žâ€­(â€­â€­82â€¬â€¬|â€­-â€­14â€¬â€¬)â€¬â€Ž
15 â€Žâ€­(â€­â€­81â€¬â€¬|â€­â€­16â€¬â€¬)â€¬â€Ž
```

You seem to have used the [Left-to-right mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) (â€Žâ€­), and the encoding was swapped once or twice.

You could clean it, because it's from a website. My first guess would be that your browser settings are not correct (wrong encoding set).

You can still try cleaning it.

Code:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9_\n %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]");
data = rgx.Replace(data, "");
```

Comment: ok so how should I negate this effect?
I want to be able to parse the coordinate into 2 ints.
and thanks.

Comment: copy paste from a website (with alot more data but I don't have any problems with the rest of it only with the coordinates).

Comment: Please post this website, maybe they added the random characters to trip you up, or you might have improper settings on your browser.

Comment: the coordinates are links, when I changed the encoding I started seing these â€Ž‭ characters, but on UTF-8 I see it clean.
and is there any option to do it through the VS? without going to external sites?

Comment: UTF-8 is not clean. You can see that there are invisible character, changing the encoding didn't work. My best guess is that the source of the website's encoding is messed. If you don't mind, can you post the website in question?

Comment: it's the travian web-game.
and how can I do it with C# regex?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34929/discussion-between-sagi-rokach-and-dave-chen)